# Add Class to Parent <li> when checking a child href

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the twitter Bootstrap framework and I want to change the active link depending on the page showing. (If this is not appropriate for Stackoverflow, just delete it)

Basic nav menu html is below.  Notice the class 'active'?  This highlights the active link.

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="default.aspx">View Programs</a></li>
   <li><a href="addprogram.aspx">Add Programs</a></li>
   <li><a href="contacts.aspx">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery Code ... I remove the class 'active' from all li tags and add it back to the li tag with the link to the page showing.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("ul.nav > li").removeAttr("class");
        $("ul.nav > li a[href*='contacts.aspx']").parent("ul.nav > li").addClass("active");
    });
```

This know gives me ...

```
 <ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="default.aspx">View Programs</a></li>
   <li><a href="addprogram.aspx">Add Programs</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="contacts.aspx">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

This works, but is it the correct way to do it?

Comment: I dont see any harm the way you did.

Comment: selectors like `a[href*='contacts.aspx']` are not used commonly, the better way is to give classes view-programs, add-programs and contacts respectively to the three links. Then you can simply access them by say `a.add-programs` . This is recommended because you dont have to change the code even if you change the filename or link later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you did is fine. But instead of removing the class attribute in the tag, I would do this instead because in the future you may play with multiple classes.

```
$("ul.nav > li").removeClass("active");
```

Comment: I removed it because otherwise it would leave an empty class attribute ... that didn't feel right, so I pulled the whole thing out.  Its a simple site menu, so I don't see any other classes being added.

Comment: that's okay too, at the end of the day, as long as it works without error its fine. (and if no one else has to maintain it)

Answer (score 0):

There's a ton of ways to do it...

```
$(function () {
    // I'd just use removeClass()
    $("ul.nav > li").removeClass("active");

    // And just grab the closest() list-item, just easier to read
    $("ul.nav > li a[href*='contacts.aspx']").closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you have very selectors.  Try to avoid them for better performance (if you care).

> $("ul.nav > li").removeAttr("class");

this line does not look right. Instead I would do

> $("ul.nav > li").removeClass("active");

regarding this line

> $("ul.nav > li a[href*='contacts.aspx']").parent("ul.nav > li").addClass("active");

are you sure you cannot marl LI as active on the server side?

Be aware you my have security issues if you cut "contacts.aspx" from the URL.

Comment: Can you explain the security issue?  If the url is cut down to just the root, it will default to default.aspx.

Comment: url may have JS code and your code may inject it into the page